# 'Error 403: The account for the specified project has been disabled' while accessing google cloud storage API from java

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

created multiple accounts, every time 1$ charged from cc.then I am able to create bucket in https://console.cloud.google.com/, after that I start accessing the bucket from my java code as bellow,  then account getting blocked, I tried multiple times.

java code :

**creating credentials**

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
        scopes.add(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL);

        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(
                        propsReaderUtil.getValue(ACCOUNT_ID_PROPERTY))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(propsReaderUtil.getValue(
                                PRIVATE_KEY_PATH_PROPERTY)).getFile()))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build(); 

        storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                credential).setApplicationName(
                        propsReaderUtil.getValue(APPLICATION_NAME_PROPERTY))
                .build();
```

**uploading stream**
Storage storage = getStorage();

```
    StorageObject object = new StorageObject();

    object.setBucket(bucketName);

    InputStream stream = file.getInputStream();
    try {
        String contentType = URLConnection
                .guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
        InputStreamContent content = new InputStreamContent(contentType,
                stream);

        Storage.Objects.Insert insert = storage.objects().insert(
                bucketName, null, content);
        insert.setName(file.getName());

        insert.execute();
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, or suggest me best way to do this. 
Any suggestions appreciated... 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Error 403  is an example of an error response you receive if you try to list the buckets of a non-existent project or one in which you don't have permission to list buckets.

The account associated with the project that owns the bucket or object has been disabled. Check the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/?_ga=1.216305104.794598778.1463469357) to see if there is a problem with billing, and if not, contact account support.

More information can be found in [HTTP Status and Error Codes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes).